Pico W C/C++ SDK - Where should I implement a function to send keyboard shortcuts such as ctrl-c over Bluetooth using the BTstack hidkeyboard example
I am attempting to make a Bluetooth macro pad and I want to be able to send keyboard shortcuts using Bluetooth classic. After some research, I learnt about modifier bits using USB and I have written a function which can parse a set of commands and extract the modifier numbers and then, using the BTstack example, the key code using. However, I am struggling to find the correct place to put it. Here is my code:
const static char *payload[MAX_WORDS] = {"SHIFT-A","GUI-L","1"};

char last_char(const char *str) {
    int length = 0;

    while (str[length]!='\0') {
        length++;
    }

    if (length>0) {
        return str[length-1];
    } else {
        return '\0';
    }
}

void load_payload (const char *payload[]) {

    for(int index = 0;index<MAX_WORDS;++index) {
        const char *string = payload[index];
        int sum=0;
        if(strstr(string,"CTRL") != NULL) {
            sum+=1;
        } if(strstr(string,"SHIFT") != NULL) {
            sum+=2;
        } if(strstr(string,"ALT")!=NULL) {
            sum+=4;
        } if(strstr(string, "GUI")!=NULL) {
            sum+=8;
        } // Add to sum based on USB modifier bits
        char key = last_char(string);
        key = tolower(key);
        bool found = lookup_keycode(key, keytable_us_none, sizeof(keytable_us_none), &send_keycode);
        if(found==true) {
        send_report(sum, send_keycode);
        sleep_ms(50);
        send_report(0,0);
        }

    }
   
}

The BTstack example can be found here:
https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack/blob/master/example/hid_keyboard_demo.c
I tried inserting it into the demo text function, rather than:
// queue character
    uint8_t character = demo_text[demo_pos++];
    if (demo_text[demo_pos] == 0){
        demo_pos = 0;
    }
    queue_character(character);

But then I ran into an error meaning the function at the bottom need to be named main rather than its original name: btstack_main. After changing this the device no longer shows up when scanning for Bluetooth devices on my phone and raspberry pi 4.
Where should I insert the function and do I need to rename the function back to its original name?
